# Include all files in a folder - PHP

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to include **all** files from a folder from another folder in php. Here is my current directory structure:

```
> folder1
  main.php
> folder2
  > folder3
  someFile.php
  someFile2.php
  someFile3.json
```

I tried doing:

```
include "../folder2/";
```

and this(only includes php files):

```
foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

From `main.php`, I want to include all of `folder2/` including the sub folder: `folder3` as well as the php and json files inside `folder2/`. I have looked at other stack overflow questions and know about the for loop method but haven't figured out a way to include different file types(.php, .json, etc...) and sub directories. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `include` shouldn't be used for other file types, like `.json`. To extract data from those files you'll want to read them using something like `file_get_contents`. For example:

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('someFile3.json'));
```

To recursively include the PHP files in other directories you can try recursively searching through all directories:

```
function require_all($dir, $max_scan_depth, $depth=0) {
    if ($depth > $max_scan_depth) {
        return;
    }

    // require all php files
    $scan = glob("$dir/*");
    foreach ($scan as $path) {
        if (preg_match('/\.php$/', $path)) {
            require_once $path;
        }
        elseif (is_dir($path)) {
            require_all($path, $max_scan_depth, $depth+1);
        }
    }
}

$max_depth = 255;
require_all('folder3', $max_depth);
```

This code is a modified version of the code found here: https://gist.github.com/pwenzel/3438784